# How to Continue on Failure with a Node First Strategy without Continuing from the Failed Step

Tags: rundeck

I have a Rundeck job which runs several steps on a list of nodes with a node first strategy. I set this job to continue on node failure expecting it to execute from the first step on the next node. It instead begins the execution from the step after the step that failed on the previous node. Any idea why this is or how I can change this?

Example job definition:

```
- defaultTab: nodes
  executionEnabled: true
  group: group
  id: <id>
  multipleExecutions: true
  name: <job-name>
  nodeFilterEditable: true
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: true
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: .*-filter.com
  nodesSelectedByDefault: false
  scheduleEnabled: false
  sequence:
    commands:
    - description: first script
      script: |
        #!/bin/bash

        echo 'first script'
    - jobref:
        args: <some-args>
        group: group
        ignoreNotifications: true
        name: do something
        nodeStep: 'true'
        project: project
        uuid: <job-id>
    - description: Another script
      script:
        #!/bin/bash

        echo 'another script'
    - description: Yet another script
      script:
        #!/bin/bash

        echo 'Yet another script'
    - jobref:
        args: <args>
        group: group
        name: Job
        uuid: <job-id>
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: <id>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you share a job definition example?

Comment: Hi @MegaDrive68k, added an example to the question

Comment: You're using two child jobs: the first one on another project and the second one apparently on the same parent job project. Could you post those job examples? Take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4147#issuecomment-434364908

Comment: The child jobs each just run a couple of scripts, are pretty similar to that job bar the job references. Turns out all steps are being executed and the logs correctly report that. So this seems to be a UI issue

Comment: Hi, I just tested the similar parent job on Rundeck 4.17.1 (I tried to recreate child jobs, but with additional information, I can recreate your scenario more accurately). The three jobs and their descriptions can be found here: https://pastebin.com/FhmUkHec I can observe the expected behavior after intentionally failing on a certain step on a specific node: https://imgur.com/a0GiRpX Is the same behavior observed with Rundeck 4.17.1? It would be ideal to run tests with completely repeatable example-mock jobs (parent and child jobs).